# Robotium for Android - solo.searchText () not working

Tags: android, robotium

I'm having a problem with searchText() function used with Robotium.

I'm searching for this string:

```
<string name="provisioning_wizard_title_2">Service Activation Wizard (Step 2)</string>
```

I defined it in string xml, and I'm searching it this way:

```
Activity act=solo.getCurrentActivity(); 
String string = solo.getString(act.getResources().getIdentifier("provisioning_wizard_title_2", "string", act.getPackageName()));
```

It fails when I call

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText(string));
```

and it fails also if i call:

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Service Activation Wizard (Step 2)"));
```

even if that is the string I'm seeing in the focused screen activity.

The strange thing is that it works if I use the same string without last character:

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Service Activation Wizard (Step 2"));
```

and it works if I use

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText(string.substring(0, string.length()-1)));
```

I hope someone could help me.

Sorry for my english!

Thank you.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
I solved problem thanks to Renas Reda (Founder and maintainer of Robotium). 
The problem is due to regex support in searchText(); some characters will trigger it. 
Use Pattern.quote(string) 
Example: Pattern.qoute("provisioning_wizard_title_2") and eveything works good!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `Solo#waitForText(...)` so I make sure I'm not losing some race condition.

Try this:

`assertTrue(solo.waitForText( solo.getString(R.string. provisioning_wizard_title_2) );`

Make sure you are importing the correct `R.java` file from your production project (not the test project).

Comment: I'm making a black box text so I don't have R.java but I know from documentation the id of string declared in strings.xml so I can reference to them with code I use above.
I solved the problem using Pattern.quote(string). 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what string you are fetching. Try to log it:

```
Log.d("Debug", "String is: " + string);
```

you should rather call, here may be another issue related to package as activity may be in another package than main package of application:

```
String string = solo.getString(act.getResources().getIdentifier(act.getPackageName()+":string/provisioning_wizard_title_2"), null, null));
```

You can also get all visible texts, to make sure, what is on the screen:

```
for(TextView textView : solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class)) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Text on the screen: " + textView.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: I used Log class to check if the string I fetch was correct and it was; then I discovered problem is due to regex support in searchText() . I use Pattern.quote(string) example: Pattern.qoute("provisioning_wizard_title_2") and everything works good!