# Search date using regular expression in robotium testing

Tags: android, robotium

I have to verify whether the date and time is displayed or not. (Robotium Testing)

Format: 17/07/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)

I have tried this `assertTrue(solo.searchText(Pattern.quote("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}")));` but my test case fails.

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17741680/2811956)

Comment: @Wizard.. I did the same only using `Pattern.quote()`

Comment: regex support is not in searchText() that is how he solved his issue